# Servlet URL pattern to match all URL

Tags: spring, jsp, web.xml, url-pattern

I'm current using Spring MVC to do a project. I having problem using the url-pattern to direct my jsp page. Everytime I create a new jsp page, I have to hardcode the jsp name into the web.xml.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ShoppingCart</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<!-- Once DispatcherServlet is initialized will look for file name [servlet-name]-servlet.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <!-- all request matches with <url-pattern> will be handled by DispatcherServlet instance named dispatcher -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/login.jsp</url-pattern>        
    <url-pattern>/update.jsp</url-pattern>        
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Image below is my folder structure

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOELo.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify your servlet general `url-mapping` on `web.xml` and then handle  its sub `URLS`  on your controllers

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Configure an `InternalResourceViewResolver` bean on your `dispatcher-context.xml`

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

On your Controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ControllerRegister{

  @RequestMapping("register") 
  public String goToRegisterPage(){
      return "register";
  }

}
```

this will serve `register.jsp` under folder `WEB-INF/views/` wehn calling `URL`:

```
http://yourHost:port/yourApp/register
```

Comment: Hi Rafik BELDI, thank you for your help. Now my pages are working. Thanks!